# c# MVVM Custom DialogEvent

Tags: c#, user-interface, events, mvvm

In my application i have mainViewModels for each of my tabs, the tabs are completely seperate. Theyre linked to actual xaml usercontrols with a dialogservice.

Then i have lets say an OrderVM, its a viewmodel that represents an order. It implements onPropertyChanged and custom validation.

If i change a property and it requires user input, how do i get back to showing a dialog from within this OrderViewModel?

First i thought about simply putting in a reference to the parent mainViewModel, or the dialogservice itself, but that couples them very tightly and i cant test my OrderVM independently, since it'll crash if there is no initialized dialogservice or no parent.

I also thought about simply listening for the OnPropertyChanged event, but then all the logic regarding Orders is in the mainViewModel, instead of in the OrderViewModel. So if i were to reuse the OrderVM to display/edit it somewhere else in the application, i'd have duplicate logic in both the mainVMs.

What i did now, is create a custom dialog event in my OrderVM and listen for it in the mainVM, then change a property in the arguments object to reflect the users choice.

Is that "correct"? It feels a little better to me, but still off. Since if there is no one listening for my event, it'll always be false. But i can never be sure with events that anyone is listening right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should deem what is correct in your situation, I cannot do that, but one thing I can say is that you would benefit from using dependency injection. I would think that the implementation of the dialog service is hidden behind a interface, and that interface can be mocked in tests of the view model, thus creating using tests for your scenario would pose no problems, or have I misunderstood your problem?